# How to create a class with multiple method and then pass the values back to the main method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to create a class that has a few methods in it. I am attempting to only pass the values entered by the user into the methods. Then, each method is run and the value is printed in the main method. Here is what I have.

```
public class HotelRating{
   private int hotel = 0;
   private int years = 0;
   int [][] Ratingarray = new int [hotel][years];

   public HotelRating(){
   }


   public HotelRating(int hotel, int years){
   this.hotel = hotel;
   this.years = years;
        for (int row = 0; row < Ratingarray.length; row++){
         for (int column = 0; column < Ratingarray[row].length; column++){
            Ratingarray[row][column] = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);
         }
      }
   }

   public String fiveStarsHotels(){
      String result = "";
      System.out.print("Five stars hotels indices: ");
      System.out.println();
      for (int row = 0; row < Ratingarray.length; row++){
         for (int column = 0; column < Ratingarray[row].length; column++){
            switch (Ratingarray[row][column]){
               case 1:
                  break;
               case 2:
                  break;
               case 3:
                  break;
               case 4:
                  break;
               case 5:
                  result = (row + 1 + ",");
            }
         }
      }
      return result;
   }

  }
```

Here is how I am attempting to call this method in the main method:

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestHotelRating{
   public static void main (String[] args){
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println ("Please enter the amount of hotels: ");
         int hotel = input.nextInt();

         System.out.println ("Please enter the number of years: ");
         int years = input.nextInt();

         HotelRating myObject = new HotelRating (hotel, years);

         System.out.println(myObject.fiveStarsHotels());
      }
   }
}
```

When I call the method, it returns nothing. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Your array always has 0 row and 0 column, since you initialize with hotel and years, that are initialized to 0. Put the array initialization in the constructor, and use the arguments passed to the constructor. The two int fields are useless.

Comment: So your saying declare the array outside of the constructor but initialize it inside the constructor?

Comment: Yes. That's what a constructor is for: initializing fields.

Comment: If you used a debugger, you would have been able to find out for yourself that the array is empty. Learning to use a debugger is an important part of learning to code.